# Pass ng-data to scope

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to create a live search function with AngularJS. I got a input field:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" data-ng-model="title" class="search">
```

it there away to pass the search keyword inside the scope so i can perform a live search (JS) and display the results directly to the DOM

```
var app = angular.module("DB", []);

app.controller("Controller", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.details = [],

  $http.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
    $http.get('http://api.org/search?query=<need to pass search name here>&api_key=').

    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      //handle errors
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the angular controller use a watch expression.

```
$scope.$watch('title', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  if(newValue != oldValue) {
    $http.get('http://api.org/search?query=' + newValue + '&api_key=')
         .success(function(data, status, headers, config) { /* Your Code */ })
         .error(function(data, status, headers, config) { /* Your Code */ });
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer it helped me! Is there also a empty state so it will remove the data after the searchfield is empty?

Comment: @Frenck Removed the additional conditional check of `newValue` from `if` statement. Now, you will able to clear when field is empty. Please try to analyse what code is written. It's just a simple `if` statement, where you need to alter to met your empty state.

Comment: thanks do i need to check the length to find the empty state? I also need to hide it then do i need something like ng-hide i have no clue

Comment: Whenever the input it empty its gets into the .error because there is no search keyword

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" data-ng-model="title" class="search" data-ng-change="search()">

app.controller("Controller", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.details = [],

  $scope.search= function() {
    var url = "http://api.org/search?query="+$scope.title+"&api_key=";
     $http.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
     $http.get(url).

    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      //handle errors
  });
  };     
});
```

Comment: 1. url variable is a local variable in `$scope.search` function so you will have `undefind` in `$http.get(url)` 2. in `$scope.search` should be `+$scope.title+` not `+title+` 3. it will not perform search, as you only set url varialbe in `$scope.search` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use watch as @Justin John proposed, or can use `ng-change` 
when using `ng-change` your controller should look something like this

```
app.controller("Controller", function($scope, $http) {

  $http.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json"; //should be moved to run block of your app
  $scope.details = [];

  $scope.search= function() {
    $http.get("http://api.org/search?query="+$scope.title+"&api_key=")
       .success(function(data, status, headers, config) { .... })
       .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {//handle errors });
  }
});
```

and your html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" data-ng-model="title" class="search" data-ng-change="search()">
```